# How can I make a button to import data from an excel table into my access table?

Tags: database, ms-access

I am trying to make a button so that when you click it you can choose an excel file and upload it to the database table. Would you be able to help me?

## Example

================

ID  Name    Position    Company Start Date  Stop Date   CV Date CV in Order ID-2

1   Joe Nurse   BRC 10-Jan-12       20-Oct-09   yes
123    Paul CO  CGH 10-Feb-12           yes 14

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate the Office [FileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195878%28v=office.11%29.aspx):

```
Dim fd As FileDialog 
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) 
If fd.Show Then
    MsgBox "file choosen was " & fd.SelectedItems(1)
End If
```

You need to add a reference (in VBA) to the Office Object Library to run this code.

You could then use `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` to import the Excel file.

Comment: If you want to avoid an error (*5: "Invalid procedure call or argument"*) when the user clicks Cancel in the `FileDialog`, put the `MsgBox` in an `If` block: `If fd.Show Then`

Comment: Thanks @HansUp. It was just a quick example to give the idea but, yes, it's still sensible to include this. Ta.

Comment: @HansUp. I didn't take it as a criticism :). Thanks again.

Comment: @HansUp I tend to get the reference then later remove it (converting to `Object`). I'm reluctant to explain the difference all the time though ;)